# YouTube Data API: published changes in the description don't appear in YouTube Studio

Tags: api, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

We use the [YouTube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3) to publish changes in metadata like video title or video description. Now, when changing the title via API, changes instantly show up on the user-facing video page ([https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={videoID}](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=%7BvideoID%7D)) as well as in YT Studio. When changing the description of a video, changes sometimes never appear in YT Studio! The user-facing video page is updated right away, but the changes never show in YT Studio!

Has anybody else experienced issues like that? I tried to reach out to YT support, but they are not responsive.

Hope to find a solution here!

We are using the youtube module from [googleapis NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis).

The code looks as follows:

```
/**
* example for snippet: {description: 'my changed title'}
**/
async publish(id, snippet) {
    const auth = this._utilService.getOAuthClient();
    const params: any = {
        auth,
        part: ['snippet'],
        requestBody: {
            id,
            snippet,
        },
    };

    return youtube.videos.update(params);
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include [example]